# How to add examples a component with dependencies in react-styleguidist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-styleguidist

I would like to document a `ButtonGroup` component rendering `Button` components within it using `react-styleguidist'.

I have a styleguidist webpack config which looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          }
        ],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'
}
```

> I know that I dont need to define commonly used loaders and plugins because styleguidist already adds them internally

Inside the `src/components/`, the directory structure for allowing `styleguidist` to pick up my components looks a little like this:

```
 Button
   index.js
   Readme.md
   ButtonGroup
     index.js
     example.js (created for Case II after Case I failed)
     Readme.md
```

**Case I**

In my `Readme.md` within the `ButtonGroup` directory:

````
```jsx
const Button = require('../index')

<ButtonGroup>
  <Button type='primary' size='lg'>Hello, World</Button>
  <Button type='primary' size='lg'>Hello, Doctor</Button>
</ButtonGroup>
```
````

When I do that, my `styleguide` has an error that says:

```
SyntaxError: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (5:2)
```

**Case II**

I have tried enclosing the information in an `example.js` inside `ButtonGroup` directory as illustrated above, the file contains:

```
import React from 'react'

const ButtonGroup = require('./index')
const Button = require('../index')

export default function ButtonGroupExample (props) {
  return (
    <ButtonGroup>
      <Button>Hello, World</Button>
      <Button>Hello, Doctor</Button>
    </ButtonGroup>
  )
}
```

Now the example component is imported into the `Readme.md`:

````
```jsx
const Example = require('./example')
 (<Example />)
```
````

which throws the error:

```
TypeError: require(...) is not a function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I know that I dont need to define commonly used loaders and plugins because styleguidist already adds them internally

This is not true. Styleguidist doesn’t add any loaders to your code.

> SyntaxError: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (5:2)

Most likely you need a semicolon after `;`. And probably you don’t need to require a `Button` component. It depends on your style guide config and whether you want to show your `Button` component in a style guide.

If you want to show both components in a style guide, point Styleguidist to all you components: `components: 'src/components/**/index.js'`.

If you want to hide some components from a style guide but be able to use them in examples, enable `skipComponentsWithoutExample` option an use `require` option to load your components:

```
// styleguide.config.js
module.exports = {
  skipComponentsWithoutExample: true,
  require: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'styleguide/setup.js')
  ]
}

// styleguide/setup.js
import Buttom from './src/components/Button';
global.Button = Button;
```

> Case II

I’m not sure what you’re trying to do here.

Comment: Removing the require helped, it is good that components within a styleguide can reference one another. Thanks, regarding config, I mean unlike storybook which might need a full control mode, storybook provides no such option