# Cannot use other components as children in React Styleguidist documentation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-styleguidist

I'm using React Styleguidist (version 8.0.6) to document React components. I have a directory structure like this:

```
Card
- Card.js
- Card.md
ActionItems
- ActionItems.js
- ActionItems.md
```

Each of these 2 components renders correctly on its own Styleguidist-generated page.

However in `Card.md`, I want one of my Card examples to contain an `<ActionItems/>` component as a child, like this:

```
<Card>
    <ActionItems/>
</Card>
```

The only example I've found of someone else doing something like this is [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46067207/how-to-add-examples-a-component-with-dependencies-in-react-styleguidist).

If I put the following in my `Card.md`:

````
```jsx
<Card someAttr="foo">
    <ActionItems someOtherAttr="bar"/>
</Card>
```
````

Styleguidist errors out with `SyntaxError: Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for <React.Fragment>`.

As per the stack overflow article I linked earlier, I tried this

````
```jsx
const ActionItems = require('../ActionItems/ActionItems.js');

<Card someAttr="foo">
    <ActionItems someOtherAttr="bar"/>
</Card>
```
````

but Styleguidist then gives me a different error: `Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag`.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Or does Styleguidist just not allow you to do what I want to do?

---

In case it's relevant, if I change the require path to *anything* else e.g. `'/www/javascript/ActionItems/ActionItems.js`, Styleguidist fails with the following message

```
Failed to compile
Module not found: Can't resolve '/www/javascript/ActionItems/ActionItems.js' in '/www/javascript/react-components/Card'
```